# Enumerate all 16-digit integers $t$ such that $12t+5,15t+8,20t+11,30t+17$ are all prime numbers

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, algorithms

$t$ is a 16-digit integer, and $12t+5,15t+8,20t+11,30t+17$ are all prime numbers. Enumerate all such $t$'s

I tried to sieve based on residue classes. For example, for $12t+5,15t+8,20t+11,30t+17$ to not be divisible by $2,3,5,7$, $t$ has to satisfy that

$$
\begin{aligned}
t &\not\equiv 0 \quad &\mod 2 \\
t &\not\equiv 2 \quad &\mod 3 \\
t &\not\equiv 0 \quad &\mod 5 \\
t &\not\equiv 2,4,6 \quad &\mod 7 \\
\end{aligned}
$$

So I'd

1. Find such residue conditions for the first $n$ prime numbers $\{p_1,p_2,\dots,p_n\}$.
2. Find all integers $k<\prod_{1\leq i\leq n} p_i=P$ that meet those conditions.
3. Enumerate all $k+iP$ with 16 digits.
4. Find those that meet the primality conditions.

Step 2 scans through $P$ numbers and step 3 scans through ~ $10^{16}/P$ so I think $n=8$ or $n=9$ would be optimal? But this process still takes beyond a reasonable amount of time.

My question:

1. How many such $t$'s are there (exactly or approximately)?
2. What is a better procedure to enumerate such $t$?

Comment: Here is something interesting :) Let's say $p = 15t + 8$ and $q = 30t + 17$. Then you have $2p + 1 = q$. This makes $(p,q)$ a Sophie Germain prime couple! There are some estimates on number of such $p < n$. [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sophie_Germain_prime)

Comment: Note that also $t \not\equiv 0 \pmod{11}$ and $t \not\equiv 0 \pmod {17}$.

Answer (score 4):

Roughly speaking, $n$ has $\frac 1{\log n}$ chance of being prime.  Your numbers are about $2\cdot 10^{16}$,  so they have about $1$ chance in $37.5$ of being prime.  If you picked four uncorrelated numbers of this size you would have about $\frac 1{37.5^4}\approx \frac 1{2\ 000\ 000}$ chance they were all prime.   In general, there are $48$ moduli that are coprime to $210$ so for four uncorrelated numbers you would have about $0.00273$ chance they would all be coprime to $210$.

I find there are $32$ values for $t \bmod 210$ that have all four coprime to $210$, so your chance is about $0.152$.  This improves your odds by a factor $\frac {0.152}{0.00273}\approx 55.8$  It would suggest that about $1\ t$ in $36\ 000$ would work.  As there are $9 \cdot 10^{15}\ 16$ digit numbers, there should be about $2.5\cdot 10^{11}$ values of $t$ that have all four prime.  That is a long list.